# "NullInjectorError: No provider for Subscription! Why I get this error in the console?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscription, observers

Here is what I'm doing in a componemt:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private firstObsSubscription: Subscription) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    interval(1000).subscribe((count) => console.log(count));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.firstObsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Component is than bundled into module, which is later injected into another module.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, UserComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Apparently, I'm doing something wrong here

Comment: As the error says: there's nothing to provide the `Subscription` that your component's constructor expects. It's not clear to me what the fix is without more context about what the subscription is expected to do.

Comment: You placed `private firstObsSubscription: Subscription` in a constructor of a component, so framework will need to create an instance of this component by passing `Subscription` object to this component constructor, and it will look into `providers` to find the provider that will fullfill this object. And there is probably none. So the question is why you put it as a component parameter and not as a plain class field, or if it is intended - where did you register a provider to fulfill this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is this:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private firstObsSubscription: Subscription
  
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstObsSubscription = interval(1000).subscribe((count) => console.log(count));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.firstObsSubscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

As others mentioned in the comments: IF you add a parameter to a constructor in an Angular Application, Angular will try to find a dependency of that type which is not available in your case. And probably shouldn't be in this particular case.